# Unable To install TailwindCSS

Tags: css, node.js, tailwind-css

Whenever i try to install the Tailwindcss i got a error says

```
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

i have updated my node to 20.3.1 and i have also install the extention of tailwindcss in vscode.

I read the docs of tailwind and follow same steps but no utility class were found

My Terminal

```
PS C:\Users\anura\Desktop\Tailwind CSS> npm install -D tailwindcss

added 83 packages in 9s

14 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
PS C:\Users\anura\Desktop\Tailwind CSS> npm fund
Tailwind CSS
├── https://github.com/sponsors/sindresorhus
│   └── @alloc/quick-lru@5.2.0
├─┬ https://paulmillr.com/funding/
│ │ └── chokidar@3.5.3
│ └── https://github.com/sponsors/jonschlinkert
│     └── picomatch@2.3.1
├─┬ https://opencollective.com/postcss/
│ │ └── postcss@8.4.24, postcss-js@4.0.1, postcss-load-config@4.0.1, postcss-nested@6.0.1
│ └── https://github.com/sponsors/ai
│     └── nanoid@3.3.6
├── https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb
│   └── resolve@1.22.2, is-core-module@2.12.1, supports-preserve-symlinks-flag@1.0.0
├── https://github.com/sponsors/feross
│   └── run-parallel@1.2.0, queue-microtask@1.2.3
└── https://github.com/sponsors/isaacs
    └── glob@7.1.6

PS C:\Users\anura\Desktop\Tailwind CSS> npx tailwindcss init

Created Tailwind CSS config file: tailwind.config.js
PS C:\Users\anura\Desktop\Tailwind CSS> npx tailwindcss -i ./src/style.css -o ./dist/style.css --watch     

Rebuilding...

warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Done in 207ms.
```

And tailwind.config.js file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./dist/index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

[![This is my All Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKuTb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKuTb.png)
```

Comment: What is in `./dist/index.html`? The warning implies there are no Tailwind css classes found in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks good, but to use Tailwind utilities classes, double check that you added properly theses directives on the top of your style.css file.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation